# beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents not triggering events for Apple Music

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmusicplayercontroller, apple-music

I am playing Apple Music from my application , the apple music player code is as -

```
-(void) submitAppleMusicTrackWithProductID: (NSString *) productID // productID in US is the last numbers after i= in the share URL from Apple Music
{

    [SKCloudServiceController requestAuthorization:^(SKCloudServiceAuthorizationStatus status) {
        NSLog(@"status is %ld", (long)status);
        SKCloudServiceController *cloudServiceController;
        cloudServiceController = [[SKCloudServiceController alloc] init];
        [cloudServiceController requestCapabilitiesWithCompletionHandler:^(SKCloudServiceCapability capabilities, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            NSLog(@"%lu %@", (unsigned long)capabilities, error);

            if (capabilities >= SKCloudServiceCapabilityAddToCloudMusicLibrary || capabilities==SKCloudServiceCapabilityMusicCatalogPlayback)
            {
                NSLog(@"You CAN add to iCloud!");
                [[MPMediaLibrary defaultMediaLibrary] addItemWithProductID:productID completionHandler:^(NSArray<__kindof MPMediaEntity *> * _Nonnull           entities, NSError * _Nullable error)
                 {
                     NSLog(@"added id%@ entities: %@ and error is %@", productID, entities, error);
                     NSArray *tracksToPlay = [NSArray arrayWithObject:productID];
                 [[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setQueueWithStoreIDs:tracksToPlay];
                    [[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] stop];
                 [[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] play];
                   self.isTrackChangedByNextPreviousButton = NO;

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                              selector:@selector(handleTrackChanged:)
                                                                  name:MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification
                                                                object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                              selector:@selector(handlePlaybackStateChanged:)
                                                                  name:MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
                                                                object:nil];


                     [[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications];
                     [[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setRepeatMode: MPMusicRepeatModeNone];
                 }];


            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Blast! The ability to add Apple Music track is not there. sigh.");
            }

        }];

    }];
}

-(void)handleTrackChanged:(id )notification
{
    if (!self.AppleMusicPreviuosTrack)
    {        
        self.AppleMusicPreviuosTrack = [[Tracks alloc] init];
    }
    if (self.AppleMusicPreviuosTrack.trackId == self.CurrentTrack.trackId && [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer].currentPlaybackRate == 0 && !self.isSongChangedManually)
    {
        self.isSongChangedManually = YES;
        [self FilterArtistsTracks:@"next" :^(Tracks *track, NSError *err)
         {

         }];

    }
    else
    {
     if ([[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] currentPlaybackRate]==1)
     {
    self.AppleMusicPreviuosTrack.trackId = self.CurrentTrack.trackId;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kTrackChanged object:nil];
         //Delay execution of my block for 20 seconds.
 dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 30 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     self.isSongChangedManually = NO;
 });

     }
    }
}

-(void)handlePlaybackStateChanged:(id )notification
{
    NSLog(@"handle_PlaybackStateChanged");
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kDidTrackPlaybackStatus object:nil];
    if ([MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer].currentPlaybackRate>0)
    {
        [self.playerMenuView.playpauseButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.playerMenuView.playpauseButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

}
```

which is working great . Now I wants to control the track from lock screen, for this i did following code in `viewWillAppear`

```
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
   [APP_DELEGATE becomeFirstResponder];
```

and `remoteControlReceivedWithEvent` method is written in `AppDelegate` file as follows -

```
-(void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    switch (event.subtype)
    {
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause:
            [APP_DELEGATE PlayPauseMusic:nil];
            //[streamer pause];
            break;
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay:
            [APP_DELEGATE PlayPauseMusic:nil];
            //[streamer start];
            break;
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause:
            [APP_DELEGATE PlayPauseMusic:nil];
            //[streamer pause];
            break;
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlStop:
            [APP_DELEGATE PlayPauseMusic:nil];

            //[streamer stop];
            break;
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlNextTrack:

            [APP_DELEGATE next:nil];

            break;
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPreviousTrack:
            [APP_DELEGATE previous:nil];


            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

**Note -** The `remoteControlReceivedWithEvent` triggered every time if `iTunes` tracks are playing by `AVPlayer` OR `Spotify` tracks are playing by Spotify iOS SDK .

But same code is not triggering while playing Apple Music tracks by -

```
[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer]      

                 or

 [MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer]
```

any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Also trying to figure this out!

Comment: hey, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `-(void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event` to track for the controls, use `MPRemoteCommandCenter` adding targets to each one of the controls:

> Note: It's important to enable the controls before assigning a target.

```
[MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].playCommand.enabled = YES;
[[MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].playCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(remotePlay)];

[MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].pauseCommand.enabled = YES;
[[MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].pauseCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(remoteStop)];

[MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].previousTrackCommand.enabled = YES;
[[MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].previousTrackCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(loadPreviousSong)];

[MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].nextTrackCommand.enabled = YES;
[[MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].nextTrackCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(loadNextSong)];
```

Selectors:

```
-(void) remotePlay {
    [APP_DELEGATE PlayPauseMusic:nil];
}
-(void) remoteStop {
    [APP_DELEGATE PlayPauseMusic:nil];
}
-(void) loadNextSong {
    [APP_DELEGATE next:nil];
}
-(void) loadPreviousSong {
    [APP_DELEGATE previous:nil];
}
```

Comment: You got these functions to be called when using MPMusicPlayerController? I can't get it to fire.

Comment: Try Enabling your ViewController as First Responder with -  (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder { return true; }

Comment: Hm tried that, but I am going to try again. I just want to make sure you actually got it working?

Comment: I already used there functions & didn't get working in my app.

Comment: I've filed a bug report with apple. Anyone have any other ideas?